# Eclipse fails to compile C project when using a flags

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I'm trying to compile a C project with Eclipse, under Ubuntu 12.10 using GCC.

When I use these flags:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxkG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVA2k.jpg

eclipse fails to compile.

The compilation error is the following:

```
error: ISO C forbids an empty translation unit [-pedantic]
make: *** [.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o] Error 1
```

Why do these problems appear, 
and how should I compile with eclipse with the checked flags?

When trying to compile manually from the `Terminal` with these flags, it compiles successfully. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your C project has an empty source file.

You can either:

1) Remove that file. If it is empty why do you need it?

2) Be more relax with your compilation flags,  with `-pedantic` instead of `-pedantic-errors` for example

3) Add some dumb code to make `gcc` believe the file is not empty, for example add `#include <stdio.h>`.